# Not all kafka consumers are getting assigned to partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 10 consumers and 10 partitions.
I take the number of partitions

```
int partitionCount = getPartitionCount(kafkaUrl);
```

and I create the same number of consumers with the same **group.id**.

```
    public void listen() {
        try {
            String kafkaUrl = getKafkaUrl();
            int partitionCount = getPartitionCount(kafkaUrl);
            Stream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                    .limit(partitionCount)
                    .forEach(index -> executorService.execute(() ->
                            consumerTask.invokeKafkaConsumerTask(prepareConsumerConfig(index, kafkaUrl), INPUT_TOPIC)));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Cannot receive event from kafka ", exception);
        }


    public void invokeKafkaConsumerTask(Properties properties, String topicName) {
        try(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)) {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName));
            logger.info("[KAFKA] consumer created");
            invokeKafkaConsumer(consumer);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            logger.error("Cannot create kafka consumer ", exception);
        }
    }

    private void invokeKafkaConsumer(KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
                if (consumerRecords.count() > 0) {
                    consumeRecords(consumerRecords);
                    consumer.commitSync();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while receiving records ", e);
        }
    }
```

method **getPartitionCount**
return 10 partitions so it's working right

config looks like this

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, CONSUMER_CLIENT_ID);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, CONSUMER_CLIENT_ID + index);
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "300000");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
```

what I see after assigning consumers to the partition

```
TOPIC      PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CLIENT-ID                                                        
topicName  1          89391           89391           0               consumer0
topicName  3          88777           88777           0               consumer1
topicName  5          89280           89280           0               consumer2
topicName  4          88776           88776           0               consumer2
topicName  0          4670991         4670991         0               consumer0
topicName  9          23307           89343           66036           consumer4
topicName  7          89610           89610           0               consumer3
topicName  8          88167           88167           0               consumer4
topicName  2          89138           89138           0               consumer1
topicName  6          88967           88967           0               consumer3
```

only half of the consumers have been assigned to the partitions
why did this happen? 
There should be one consumer per partition acording to documentation.
 Am I doing something wrong?
 **kafka version 2.1.1**.

I also find few this logs ->

```
Setting newly assigned partitions:[empty]
```

Comment: What is the configuration of property `auto.leader.rebalance.enable`?

Comment: I don't see it in the configuration but in logs i can see `auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true`

Comment: Can you share the output of `kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper my_zookeeper_ip:2181 --topic yourTopicName`

Comment: the same as in my description -> PARTITION from 0-9 and CONSUMER-ID from 0-4 each consumer has 2 partitions https://ctxt.io/2/AABABWsYEg

Comment: My bad. It was meant to be `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <kafka_brokers> --describe –group <consumer_group_id>`

Comment: this is how it looks https://ctxt.io/2/AABAWfgaFg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207842/discussion-between-michalavis-and-giorgos-myrianthous).

Comment: Have you tried using other, higher level Kafka libraries, by chance? Like Kafka Streams or Spring?

Comment: Can you provide your full source code?

Comment: I pasted almost the entire code we have stream based on the number of partitions and we create kafka consumers there that all subscribe to one topic and poll records in while loop

Comment: @AshishBhosle https://www.codepile.net/pile/NMo9Q2WV Here you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solution] interesting case I changed group.id and partition.assignment.strategy, added auto.offset.reset=earliest and it looks like it works...

Answer (score -1):

Are you subscribing to a collection of topic name or java Pattern?
  If you are subscribing to a Pattern , change `partition.assignment.strategy` to `RoundRobinAssignor` or `StickyAssignor`.

Comment: it's String - topic name and strategy is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor